What is the termux command to open a closed port?
I recently closed a tcp port on termux and need to know the commands to open it again?
Used kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:port# -sTCP:LISTEN)commands to close a port
Need to know the same to open? If anyone knows how to do this or has a answer for me please reply.
